# Multiple Input lines java

Tags: java, input

I want to write a program that reads this input:

> ```
> 1
> 3
> 9
> 16
> 25
> 17
> 150312
> 0.5
> 13.8
> 2.4
> ```

and it should output this:

```
1.00,1.00
3.00,1.73
9.00,3.00
16.00,4.00
25.00,5.00
17.00,4.12
150312.00,387.70
0.50,0.71
13.80,3.71
2.40,1.55
```

My Code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SqrtTable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
        if(StdIn.isEmpty()==true) {
        }
        else {
            output(s);
        }
    }

    public static void output(Scanner s) {
        double a = StdIn.readDouble();
//      
        StdOut.printf("%.2f, %.2f", a, Math.sqrt(a));
//      System.out.println(a);
        StdIn.readLine();
    }
}
```

My Code only puts out the first line.
What do I have to change?

Comment: `My Code only puts out the first line`, because your writing only the first line

Comment: You don't have any kind of loop here. What makes you think that this code should handle more values than one?

Comment: BTW `if(StdIn.isEmpty()==true) {` doesn't look right. Standard input is blocking structure, so it thread wants to read from it (and test its content) it will be paused (will have to wait) until there will be some content. I am not sure where did you get `StdIn` `StdOut` classes from but they probably have similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String myString = sc.nextLine();
String[] flostr = myString.split(" ");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

for(String s : flostr){
   System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(s) +" ," + df.format(Math.sqrt(Float.parseFloat(s))));
}
```

Edit: Considering user input will be in different line, try something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

   System.out.println("Enter your numbers, enter 'end' when done: ");
   while(!sc.hasNext("end")){
       list.add(sc.next());
   }

   String[] flostr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
   for(String s : flostr){
       System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat(s)) +" ," + String.format("%.2f", (Math.sqrt(Float.parseFloat(s)))));
   }

}
```

Comment: That would make sense if OP would provide all values in one line, but based on example from question it looks like values are provided in separate lines.

Comment: @Pshemo oh.. before edit, there was a single line in a question.

Comment: Yes, before my edit data in example looked like they ware placed in one line. Since new users tend to have problems with proper formatting I suspected it could be the case here, so I peeked at raw format of question and it looked like this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0bf8a710-3e61-43a3-bbf2-112f185a7852/view-source. As you see data ware in separate lines so I edited example to reflect it https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7982d507-a3e5-49cb-9d7f-b265fcd15399/view-source. It is true that I may be misinterpreting OPs intentions but I think it is very small chance.

Comment: Yes, should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

By something like this

```
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+"); 
for(String s : splited){
System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Based on OP example showing provided input, it looks like OP is providing them in separate lines. So `str` most likely will hold single value, not line of values separated by whitespaces.

Comment: I misunderstood OP's intentions. You are correct in your other comment, there needs to be a loop so that the user's input is read continuously until otherwise.